# Accessing and using Symfony model layer from Outside the Symfony applications

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

What I have is a symfony application, which contains some entities along with some repositories. A second non-symfony application should interface with the first one for interacting with some logic written in it (in this very moment just using the entities and their proper repositories). 
Keep in mind that the first application could have its own autoload register etc.

I thought of an API class for external applications, which stays in the `app` directory. To use that the application should require a script. Here is the idea:

`app/authInterface.php` that the external application should require:

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/autoload.php';
require_once (__DIR__.'/APIAuth.php');

return new APIAuth();
```

and an example of a working APIAuth I wrote (the code is kind of messy: remember this is just a try but you can get the idea):

```
class APIAuth
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //dev_local is a personal configuration I'm using.
        $kernel = new AppKernel('dev_local', false);
        $kernel->loadClassCache();
        $kernel->boot();

        $doctrine = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
        $em = $doctrine->getManager();
        $users = $em->getRepository('BelkaTestBundle:User')->findUsersStartingWith('thisisatry');
    }
```

by calling it by the shell everything works and I'm happy with it:

```
php app/authInterface.php
```

but I'm wondering if I'm doing in the best way possible in terms of:

- **resources** am I loading just the resources I really need to run my code? Do I really need the kernel? That way everything is properly loaded - including the DB connection- but I'm not that sure if there are other ways to do it lighter
- **symfony logics** am I interacting with symfony the right way? Are there better ways?

Comment: Why don't you create a HTTP API to authenticate an external application with?

Comment: I recommend to build a proper backend with Symfony with a clear interface (e.g. by REST or XML or something similar).

Comment: `Auth` is just an example: I really need to access Symfony progammatically for a bunch of architectural constraints I have. Can we focus on the real topic? :-)

Comment: @Hidde that code-API is there because other Apps must access some information managed by the symfony app and they can't do it by means of REST apps or SOAP: imagine some php cron scripts and so forth. I could do it by simply querying the DB, but having all the Doctrine's and Symfony's facilities would be a real plus because I can abstract all the logics my appplication perfectly manags

Comment: Why don't you use a symfony command. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html

Comment: If you can't use something like an Rest Api then I recommend to go with @Hidde s proposal.

Comment: is my solution that bad? May I know why and how to do it better? I can't use a console_command because the php cron jobs are part of softwares that are developed and managed by others, but they need to interact with part of my functionalities, which I expose through the API class.
In this very moment what I need is simply interacting with the DB: I could create an API class that interacts with the DB directly, but I would prefer to use doctrine for convenience. In other words, I could simply load doctrine, but I was looking for a general approach to access any symfony resource in the future

Comment: Exactly. I will propose my thoughts in an anwer, although the question might be too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony allows using its features from the command line. If you use a CronJob or another application, and want to call your Symfony application, you have two general options:

- Generating HTTP endpoints in your Symfony application
- Generating a command which executes code in your Symfony application

Both options will be discussed below.

**HTTP endpoint (REST API)**

Create a route in your routing configuration to route a HTTP request to a Controller/Action.

```
# app/config/routing.yml
test_api:
    path:      /test/api/v1/{api_key}
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Api:test }
```

which will call the `ApiController::testAction` method.

Then, implement the `testAction` with your code you want to excecute:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

public function testAction() {
    return new Response('Successful!');
}
```

---

**Command**

Create a command line command which does *something* in your application. This can be used to execute code which can use any Symfony service you have defined in your (web)application.

It might look like:

```
// src/AppBundle/Command/TestCommand.php
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class GreetCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('myapp:section:thecommand')
            ->setDescription('Test command')
            ->addArgument(
                'optionname',
                InputArgument::OPTIONAL,
                'Test option'
            )
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $option = $input->getArgument('optionname');
        if ($option) {
            $text = 'Test '.$option;
        } else {
            $text = 'Test!';
        }

        $output->writeln($text);
    }
}
```

Look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html) for documentation.

Call your command using something like

```
bin/console myapp:section:thecommand --optionname optionvalue
```

(Use `app/console` for pre-3.0 Symfony installations.)

---

Use whichever option you think is best.

One word of advice. Do not try to use parts of the Symfony framework when your application is using the full Symfony framework. Most likely you will walk into trouble along the way and you're making your own life hard.

Use the beautiful tools you have at your disposal when you are already using Symfony to build your application.